# How do I install Jython 2.7?

Tags: python, installation, jython, robotframework

I'm trying to install Jython 2.7 to use with RobotFramework. I've downloaded all three of the jar files from http://www.jython.org/downloads.html and yet none of them actually install Jython!

I've tried running them from the command line (where a java server is opened) and just opening with java which does nothing. What am I doing wrong? I don't think that the downloads would be hosted if they didn't work.. Could it be that my other installs are affecting it?

Edit: My end goal is to use Jython with RobotFramework to run my test cases in Java

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try installing jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar. this works (I do not know which platform you are using, I have successfully installed it on Win7)

Comment: I was under the impression that you could run your tests from robot framework via Jython? How can I do this without installing the Python variant? This is a question pertaining to the installation of a language, not a server of any sort. Please correct me if I've gotten muddled somehow?

Comment: You have to install python variant too. But what I meant in my previous comment was, for Jython, use jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar

Comment: Okay, so why in the world does the b1 installer actually install Jython whilst the b2 "installer" only opens a java server?

Comment: Sorry, I never used b2. What I did is:
1. Installed python
2. Installed Jython b1 as mentioned in previous comment
3. Then proceeded with other tools used for robo, wx python et etc

Comment: More info: I had installed all of these tools as administrator (as my windows7 security stuffs had concerns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those jars are jython.  Run `java -jar <jarfile>` and you'll be in the jython command line.  There is nothing else to install.